# Numpy array dot product - "aggregate" rows without evaluating the entire thing

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I wish to calculate the inner product of a 2d numpy array with itself - i.e. np.inner(A,A) - and then for each row, extract the 2nd largest value and its index:

```
import numpy as np
import heapq

A = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
prod = np.inner(A,A)
tmp = []
for i, x in enumerate(prod): 
    idx = heapq.nlargest(2, range(len(x)), key=x.__getitem__)[1]
    max_val = heapq.nlargest(2, x)[1]
    tmp.append((i, idx, val))
```

However, if A becomes huge, it is not feasible to store the entire product in memory when effectively only two rows are needed at a time. This would be extremely easy to implement in C for example, but I'm not sure how to do it in python.

It seems that there should be an elegant way of solving it with numpy or scipy but I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: `prod` has the same size as `A`.

Comment: @hpaulj Good catch. I should have stated this in terms of A, not the product. I.e. not keeping the entirety of A in memory, just two rows at a time - and in my case A is yielded from yet another sources

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) that does `indirect partition` and thus achieves some efficiency there -

```
def nth_largest(prod): # works on prod from numpy.inner output
    idx = np.argpartition(prod,-2,axis=1)[:,-2:]
    I = np.arange(len(idx))
    idx_s = prod[I[:,None],idx].argsort(1)
    n_largest_indices = idx[I,idx_s[:,0]]
    max_vals = prod[I,n_largest_indices]
    return list(zip(I,n_largest_indices,max_vals))
```

If your primary concern is memory, resort to a loop -

```
def innerprod_nth_largest_loopy(A, k): # works on input A
    idxs = np.empty(len(A),dtype=np.uint64)
    vals = np.empty(len(A),dtype=A.dtype)
    for i,a in enumerate(A):
        r = a.dot(A.T)
        idx = np.argpartition(r,-k)[-k:]
        idxs[i] = idx[r[idx].argsort()[0]]
        vals[i] = r[idxs[i]]
    return list(zip(range(len(A)),idxs,vals))
```

Note however that the loopy version would be much slower, just good on the memory side.

Comment: Thanks - however this still requires the entire 'prod' to be calculated ahead of time, right? Suppose that A is so large that A*A simply doesn't fit in memory. And I only need 1 element (and its index) from each row, so storing the whole thing is a big waste.

Comment: @SpineFeast Added another one for memory efficiency.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering if there is a way to get the best out of both worlds using some np or sp implementations - saving memory and improving performance? Or should I just write that bit in cython?

Comment: @SpineFeast Go for cython I guess. Let us know how that goes if you go that route.

Answer (score 1):

I think for

```
prod = np.inner(A, A)
```

The i th row of `prod` is

```
prod[i, :] = np.inner(A[i, :], A)
```

So could you use a for loop and only calculate the 2nd largest value for one row at a time?